# Python relative import variable name error

Tags: python, importerror, nameerror

this is my first time using imports from one program to another with my own functions and I am receiving a name error.

I have a main program that runs functions from other relative imports. In the main program I have a variable "level" that is declared as a global variable. When the imported function is ran after the "level" has been assigned a value I am trying to use that variable and it is giving me an error that it has not been declare.

Here is an abridged version of what I have:

level.py:

```
def level_list():
    if level == '1':
       do something
    elif level ==  '2':
       do something else
    elif level == '3':
       do something else
```

main.py:

```
import level

def pick_level():
    global level
    level = input(print("Type 1, 2 or 3"))

pick_level()    
level_list()
```

Then when the function level_list is called I get nameerror "level" not defined. I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong in that level is not being assigned and brought over into the level.py, thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Show us your file structure. If using Linux, this can be seen through `tree` command.

Comment: There are many corrections here, module name and variable name should not be the same, else one will overwrite the other. And global variables have the scope at script level, global variable of main.py will not be recognized by level.py, you have to pass it explicitly.

Comment: That's where I am messing up.  I did not know how the scope of variables worked within the program and that global variables still only work in the script they are declared in, not the import. Thank you this has been a great help in pointing me in the right direction!